# How could I increase root partition size?

Tags: 18.04, disk-usage, disk-image

I want to increase the size of my root partition.

This is a screenshot of the gparted:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expand root partition without formatting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/566372/expand-root-partition-without-formatting)

Comment: You can also move /home. To move /home uses rsync- Be sure to use parameters to preserve ownership & permissions 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving  You show Windows in BIOS/MBR but also an ESP - efi system partition. Did you install Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode? You can only have one boot flag per drive and with MBR that must be on the Windows boot partition.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Answer (score 0):

- You should [backup your important data first](https://askubuntu.com/a/468533/925971)
- Boot into windows and [change locations](https://superuser.com/a/328771/1032713) of some folders such as Downloads, Documents, Music, Videos, Pictures, Desktop folders replacing `C` by `D`, so your `C` (`/dev/sda2` partition) will become less used
- [Reduce](https://superuser.com/a/1060508/1032713) `C` partition size from windows
- Prepare Ubuntu installation USB flash drive and boot into it without installing (**Try without Ubuntu installing** option in previous Ubuntu releases 19.10-)
- Run GParted
- Do **swapoff** on linux-swap partition
- Extend your Ubuntu's root partition size
- Do **swapon** on linux-swap partition
- Apply changes
- Reboot

**I've not tested it with GPT/EFI disks, so make sure you have backed up your important data or wait for more reliable answer or investigate it yourself**

Answer (score 0):

1. Backup *anything you don't want to lose* to an external drive, another PC, or the cloud
2. Verify that backup matched the source files with [checksums](https://superuser.com/questions/218544/is-there-a-copy-and-verify-command-in-ubuntu-linux/218546) or some other method
3. Repeat 1-2 using a different external drive or different PC or different cloud destination
4. Boot from an Ubuntu LiveUSB
5. In a terminal window, run `swapoff` to [turn off swapping](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/swapon.8.html)
6. Open the [Disks](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Disks) app ([more)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Disks) (and [more](https://linuxhint.com/gnome_disk_utility/))
7. Delete the dedicated swap partition by clicking on it and pressing the <kbd>-</kbd> button. Swap partitions are passe unless, as per https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq you have a special need for it. That link also discusses swap file sizing.
8. Close Disks.
9. Open [Gparted](https://gparted.org/). Remember, with it, you specify a change, then commit the change with the green checkmark [image].
10. Select the root partition. [Expand it](https://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual#gparted-resize-partition) to use the open space where the swap partition was.
11. Apply changes with that green checkmark.
12. Exit from Gparted.
13. Reboot into your Ubuntu on your internal drive.
14. [Add a swap file](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/fallocate.1.html), with the size set as per https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq with a command like `sudo fallocate -l 4G /swapfile` (here assuming a 4G swap file) ([more](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-18-04/)).
15. Alter its [permissions](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/chmod.1.html) with `sudo chmod 600 /swapfile`
16. Make it a [swap file](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/mkswap.8.html) with `sudo mkswap /swapfile`
17. [Turn on swap](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/swapon.8.html) with `sudo swapon /swapfile`
18. Make the change permanent with `sudo nano /etc/fstab` where you add a line in that /etc/fstab file  `/swapfile swap swap defaults 0 0` then save and exit from [nano](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/nano.1.html) ([more](https://nano-editor.org/) on [nano](https://nano-editor.org/dist/latest/cheatsheet.html)) with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd>
19. Make sure the swap file is set up with `sudo swapon --show`